# while installing a patch i am getting this error: 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED --

Tags: centos, patch

We are configuring lighttpd in centOS 6.4, to make enable kerberos authentication trying to install this patch.

Saving rejects to file

> /usr/local/sbin/lighttpd.rej patching file /usr/local/sbin/lighttpd

ERROR:

```
Hunk #1 FAILED at 34. 
Hunk #2 FAILED at 50.
Hunk #14 FAILED at 628.
Hunk #15 FAILED at 635.
15 out of 15 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file /usr/local/sbin/lighttpd.rej
patching file /usr/local/sbin/lighttpd
Hunk #1 FAILED at 476.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file /usr/local/sbin/lighttpd.rej
```